# "map" function in ansible changes original sequence of list

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I need to extract a variable from an inventory:

```
[all]
1.1.1.1 site=A
2.2.2.2 site=B
3.3.3.3 site=C
```

When i use:

`sites: "{{ hostvars | map('extract',hostvars,'site') | list}}"`

the resulting list is:

`["B", "A", "C"]`

Note the sequence has changed.

Now, in this particular case, i would need to preserve the original sequence, so the result must be, independent also on the sequence in which the playbook runs through the hosts (!!):

`["A", "B", "C"]`

Any ideas ?

Can i force Ansible to follow the inventory sequence strictly ? And will this also solve the map/extract problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You should not depend on the order things are defined in the inventory.  There is no guarantees this will be preserved into the in-memory representations.

The `hostvars` is a dictionary.  In, or at least older versions of python, dictionaries are not ordered by insertion order.  Hosts might be added to the hostvars in the order you define them, or the might be in some random order.